# Calculation for the entropy of binomial random graph

Tags: information-theory, entropy, random-graphs, network

In my classes, we found that for a graph $\mathbf{a}\in G(n,p)$, where we have labelled the graphs by their adjacency matrices,

$P(\mathbf{a}) = \prod _{i<j}p^{a_{ij}}(1-p)^{(1-a_{ij})}$

We define the entropy of the $G(n,p)$ ensemble to be

$S = -\sum _{\mathbf{a}\in G(n,p)}P(\mathbf{a})ln(P(\mathbf{a}))$

Now if I try to calculate this using the form of $P$, I obtain

$S = -\sum _{\mathbf{a}\in G(n,p)}\left(\prod _{i<j}p^{a_{ij}}(1-p)^{(1-a_{ij})}\right)\left(\sum_{k<l}a_{kl}ln(p) + (1-a_{kl})ln(1-p)\right)$

Now I am aware of the trick of splitting up the first summation as

$\sum_{a_{12}\in \{0,1\}}...\sum_{a_{(n-1)n}\in \{0,1\}}$

However I do not see that $S$ factorises nicely for this to be useful. In particular, the final sm with logarithms couples the $a_{ij}$, so we cannot split this up into these individual sums, as we would be able to do without the logarithm term.

Ultimately, I should obtain

$$S = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left[pln(p)+(1-p)ln(1-p)\right]$$

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to see how this comes about.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in this model the events of each edge being connected (with probability $p$) are independent. Therefore by additivity of entropy
$$
S=-\binom{n}{2} (p \ln p +(1-p) \ln (1-p))
$$
since $\binom{n}{2}$ is the total number of possible edges. Also note you are missing a minus sign (entropy is positive).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am aware of the additivity of entropy for independent events. This gives us the entropy we are aiming for, however the issue is that o do not see *how it arises from the form of P given*. And noté that the form of P in my original question clearly does indeed treat each edge independently.